# Can I redirect the recent apps button/action to the app launcher?

Tags: launcher, 8.1-oreo, keyboard-shortcuts, home-button

In short, I wondered if there was a way of configuring the home/recent apps button to go to the app launcher instead?

(Perhaps it is a software recommendations/tweaks question.)

EDIT: This lost its relevance as I have now upgraded to Android 9 where a double up swipe gets me past the downgraded recents apps view into the launcher quickly.

Comment: While I know some custom ROM (and perhaps more on rooted devices) provide customization on navigation buttons (e.g. long-pressing/double-tapping home button), I'm afraid opening app launcher really depends on the launcher app itself, so the action might not be standardized and depends on each launcher app (refer to "How to create an app drawer" section on [this custom launcher development article](https://www.androidauthority.com/make-a-custom-android-launcher-837342-837342/)), e.g. Pixel Launcher needs to swipe up, but other launchers might need different action/do nothing.

Comment: You can use GravityBox Xposed module for this or Xposed Edge Pro. I am sure there are some other good solutions as well which use Xposed framework.